# How to make a jquery click event fire only on first click

Tags: jquery

I have two divs (.basic1 and .basic2). I want .basic1 to fadeout on click, and .basic2 to fade in which I have working wonderfully. The only problem is that once .basic2 fades in, if the user continues to click the link (.navbar1), it will fade in this div over and over. I know that I need to use the .bind() function, but I can't seem to figure out where in my code to put it. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar1').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.basic2').hide().load('.basic2', function() {
            $(this).delay(600).fadeIn(1000);
            $('.basic1').fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 62):

Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('.navbar1').one('click', function(e) {
```

It unbinds the `click` event once you trigger it.

If you don't want an element to be double-clicked, something like this should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.navbar1:not(.clicked)', function() {
    // ...
});
```

To make `.navbar1` unclickable, just run `$('.navbar1').addClass('clicked')`. To make it clickable, do the opposite.

Comment: Bah, destroyed my response time. +1.

Comment: What if i only want the click function to fire if you didn't just click on .navbar1? Is that possible?

Comment: @user1745398: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but see my edit.

Comment: explained better then explained on jQuery Docs

Answer (score 9):

### Use modern Js events, with "once"!

```
const navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar1")[0];
navbar.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Add one-time callback
}, {once : true});
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once), [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)

Comment: If you need to support IE11, use events-polyfill from https://github.com/lifaon74/events-polyfill

Answer (score 8):

Please see jQuery [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for one-time event handlers. i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar1').one('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.basic2').hide().load('.basic2', function() {
            $(this).delay(600).fadeIn(1000);
            $('.basic1').fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

jQuery provides the [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method for this exactly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar1').one('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.basic2').hide() 
        .load('.basic2', function() {
            $(this).delay(600).fadeIn(1000);
            $('.basic1').fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```