# Code to update HTML link after one click?

Tags: php, html, dynamic, hyperlink, onclick

I am looking for a code, which I can put inside a standard HTML href link - that, once the link is clicked, will immediately update a portion of the link in real-time.

Something like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/<?php code(); ?>/">Example</a>
```

Will at first print:

```
<a href="http://example.com/page1/">Example</a>
```

And so after it being clicked once, it'll instantly change to:

```
<a href="http://example.com/page1-clicked/">Example</a>
```

Anyone got anything simple up the sleeve for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Use jquery to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript). Check for your answer in the link I've posted.

Answer (score 3):

First include JQuery

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Give your link an id

```
<a id="link" href="http://example.com/page1/">Example</a>
```

Use the link in your JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $(document).on("click", "#link", function() {
        $(this).attr("href", "http://example.com/page1-clicked/");
    });
});
```

**edit**

I you want to do the same with many links give your link a class

```
<a class="link" href="http://example.com/page1/">Example</a>
```

Then change the JQuery code to

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $(document).on("click", ".link", function() {
        $(this).attr("href", "http://example.com/page1-clicked/");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. However I need a dynamic code that can replace a certain word in a link on a page where there are many different links that include that word - but only clicked once should be replaced...

Comment: Edited my answer to your comment

Comment: I see, but if I need only change page1 to page1-clicked and not the whole link - how could I catch only that part? Also just to clarify please, it's not appending of the "-clicked", but switching the whole thing like so; ...com/123/ to ...com/xyz/. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery's [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler to change the link only once:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').one(function (event) {
        var elem = $(this);
        var before = elem.attr('href');
        var after = before + '-clicked/';
        elem.attr('href', after);
    })
});
```

Comment: for click once see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885660/how-to-make-a-jquery-click-event-fire-only-on-first-click