# Execute .click(function () only first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, addclass, removeclass

I trying to Execute given `.click(function()` only on first click, but it always Execute when click. 

It's works when click `.more-post-button` it will add class `loading` to `.main ul` and `show-more-post` to `.main li` after that remove Class `loading` on setTimeout function 7 second.

**JS**:

```
$(".more-post-button").click(function () {

  $('.main ul').addClass('loading');
  $('.main li').addClass('show-more-post');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.main ul').removeClass('loading');
  },7000);

});
```

My question is how to do this for only on first click, not every time click.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: after 7 second when class `loading` will removed should it work again?

Comment: Don't want `.click(function()` every time, want to first time only.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3why3vLt/1/

Comment: check this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885660/how-to-make-a-jquery-click-event-fire-only-on-first-click"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".more-post-button").one("click", function () {

  $('.main ul').addClass('loading');
  $('.main li').addClass('show-more-post');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.main ul').removeClass('loading');
  },7000);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

It'll handle it only once.

Answer (score 8):

Why complicating things, try a simple closure on that. You won't pollute globale name space, too!
Demo goes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/21dy1r3j/)

```
(function(){
'use-strict';

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var myHandler = function() {
    var click = 0;
    return function() {
        if(click === 0) {
            alert('single click');
        }
        click++;
    }
}();


button.addEventListener('click', myHandler, false);
})();
```

Comment: That a) still leaves an unused handler connected and b) is much longer code and c) is actually more complicated, not less :) Just use `one` as this *is* a jQuery question.

Comment: Javascript is all about closures. What makes you think it's complicated? The question is tagged by javascript as well, jQuery is just a framework to it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can send in the `addEventListener` an option `{ once: true }` to tell it to fire only once. So adding up to [@fubbe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702173/execute-clickfunction-only-first-click/31702550#31702550) and also using only javascript, it would be:

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var handler = function () { alert('once click'); };

button.addEventListener("click", handler, {once: true});
```

Source :

- [MDN - addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [webreflection - DOM Listener: capture, passive, and once](https://www.webreflection.co.uk/blog/2016/04/17/new-dom4-standards)

Answer (score 2):

I would use jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function. This attaches a handler that will only fire once.

**Modified JS**

```
$(".more-post-button").one("click", function () {

  $('.main ul').addClass('loading');
  $('.main li').addClass('show-more-post');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.main ul').removeClass('loading');
  },1000);

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pt9w6rz6/)

Answer (score 1):

save it in a variable:

```
var clicked = false;

  $(".more-post-button").click(function () {
  if(!clicked) {
  clicked = true;
  $('.main ul').addClass('loading');
  $('.main li').addClass('show-more-post');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.main ul').removeClass('loading');
  },7000);
}
});
```

Comment: this wouldn't work. The `.click` is a bind, so it'll happen everytime. you need to put the flag check inside the click function

Answer (score 1):

Use unbind in your function to remove all events

```
$(this).unbind();
```

From jQuery 1.7 .off is the recommended way

```
$(this).off();
```