# How to scroll down on click button 1 time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to know how i can scroll down only 1 time from homepage on click of button, if already scrolled then on click button to don't scroll down?

I'm suck with jQuery and i don't know how to do it.
Currently using this code but its always back at #what-is-it id so i don't like this:

```
  $("#scroll").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#what-is-it").offset().top},
    'slow');
          });
```

if you have solution with javascript its also welcomed.

Just want to scroll down if users is on homepage? And if he back at home page make button again scroll down him.

Comment: Is the button positioned absolute/fixed and is it always visible? Because if not, why do you want a click (where the user will expect a certain behavior, a scroll down) to not do what they want it do to?

Comment: you could use [one()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885660/how-to-make-a-jquery-click-event-fire-only-on-first-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this styling for the navbar:

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And the solution for jQuery part is in this jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnq2etu9/5/ - I think what you're looking for is this.
I just edited Sim's code to make it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yust unset your click event with jquery `off()`. Here ist the API: http://api.jquery.com/off/

So update your code like this:

```
$("#scroll").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#what-is-it").offset().top},
        'slow');
    });
    //unset click event:
    $(this).off();
});
```

another possibility is to use `one()`:

> The  .one() method is identical to  .on(), except that the handler is
>   unbound after its first invocation.

from the API: http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$("#scroll").one('click', function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#what-is-it").offset().top},
         'slow');
     });
});
```

you wrote:

> if already scrolled then on click button to don't scroll down?

unset your click function handler with the jquery onscroll function:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     $("#scroll").off();
});
```

...if the user scrolls, this unsets your click event.

**EDIT:**

I've updated the code, you posted [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7wgmac4g/1) and in the comment below:

```
//your scroll function
function scrollDown() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#nav").offset().top
    },'slow');
}

//set your handler on page load
$("body").on("click", "#scroll", scrollDown);

//scrol event handler
$(window).scroll(function() {
      var navHeight = 300; // custom nav height
      if($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
            $('#nav').addClass('goToTop');
            //finish scroll animation
            $('html,body').finish();
            //set event handler to #scroll with your scroll function
            $("body").off("click", "#scroll", scrollDown);
      } else {
            $('#nav').removeClass('goToTop');
            //unset event handler
            $("body").on("click", "#scroll", scrollDown);
      }
});
```

So this sets your click event to the button, when your navbar is stick to the top and removes it when not.
And here is a link to an example fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnq2etu9/3/

Comment: both of them is ok but what if user scroll backs to homepage and click again on button, i want to scroll down user if user is at homepage.

Comment: am i right: you've got the button on more than one site and you want that, the user only can click the button one time, no matter which page?

Comment: button is at navbar and at homepage stage nav is at bottom when scroll down navbar stick to top, so when navbar is at top button should doesnt scroll down

Comment: ok so set and unset (with on() and off()) your click events to the button in the function, where you set the navbar sticking to top, can you post your function, where you make your navbar stick to top?

Comment: i have try it your update but its same effect like `off()`  function

Comment: Next update :-) just try it. I hope, i understood your question right now.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes you understand my question but this function where you give it, its  sticking to top but its not scrolling down. Somewhere must have some mistake.

Comment: You're right, here is an example fiddle i made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnq2etu9/3/

Comment: Thanks again, well almost work, its not work if i refresh page i have to scroll so little to start to work, and when its scrolled its doesn't let me scroll down or up for couple seconds which is weird.

Comment: Notice the new jsfiddle: with this line of code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnq2etu9/3/ `$('html,body').finish();`

Comment: last one is not working, thanks for trying to help me, you have entered .nav like id i fix it its wont scrolling still.